# Edit a PDF file in browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, pdf, edit

I found that we can edit a pdf file which is uploaded in document library using `Adobe Document Cloud and SharePoint Online.`

So is there a way to edit a pdf file from a document library in the browser using `SharePoint 2016/2019 server`? Any free product or a product which can be bought in order to do it? I tried with [TextControl](https://www.textcontrol.com) and [Aspose.PDF](https://products.aspose.com/pdf) , but couldn't make it work, do not know if the problem is in my environment or they are not just working with SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Per my test in my sharepoint 2016 environment, I install Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, then I can open the pdf file in IE.

But if you want to edit the PDF file, you should buy the service.

[image]

And there are some other PDF products in the article below.

[Adobe Acrobat Alternative.](https://pdf.wondershare.com/pdf-software-comparison/adobe-acrobat-alternative.html)

Comment: Adobre Acrobat Reader DC is giving us the option to edit/view pdf file in the browser for SharePoint Online, but as I tested now for SP2016, you need to download the app and link your SharePoint site with specific account and then in the desktop application you can edit a file. So it looks like it is not possible to edit pdf file in browser with Adobe for SP2016. So the only option is to find a 3rd party tool for this if there is a one of course